# C# Datastructure with SortedDictionary() and node.Next() functionality?

Tags: c#, data-structures, sorteddictionary

How to construct/obtain a datastructure with the following capabilities:

- Stores (key,value) nodes, keys implement IComparable.
- Fast (log N) insertion and retrieval.
- Fast (log N) method to retrieve the next higher/next lower node from any node. [EXAMPLE: if
  the key values inserted are  (7,cat), (4,dog),(12,ostrich), (13,goldfish) then if keyVal referred to (7,cat), keyVal.Next() should return a reference to (12,ostrich) ].

A solution with an enumerator from an arbitrary key would of course also suffice. Note that standard SortedDictionary functionality will not suffice, since only an enumerator over the entire set can be returned, which makes finding keyVal.next require N operations at worst.

Could a self-implemented balanced binary search tree (red-black tree) be fitted with node.next() functionality? Any good references for doing this? Any less coding-time consuming solutions?

Comment: There are a number of other questions on the same subject, but none solves my problem

Comment: @willem I don't understand. Isn't enough to have only one enumerator and do `.MoveNext()`, `.MoveNext()`, ...?

Comment: @Oscar If you use .MoveNext() repeatedly to find the next node from some current node (by just iterating over the entire collection, until you find the current node, and then iterating one farther), this will be quite time consuming. I want the next node fast

Comment: @willem hmm.. that depends on how is implemented that functionality on the `SortedDictionary` class. It should be `O(n)` yield all the elements in sorted order, so everytime you do `.MoveNext()` that will be `O(1)`

Comment: Remember that when you do `MoveNext()` you're not positioning again on the position you were before. The enumerator has already started, and it will be positioned right after the `yield return` line.

Comment: @oscar: agree, everytime I use .MoveNext in SortedDictionary it will be O(1) I suppose. But if I need the next element from some arbitrary element then I need to traverse the entire collection to do just this. I would like an O(1) (or O(log(N))) method to find the next node from any current node, without having to traverse the entire collection first to find that current node.

Comment: Oh, I see you edited your question. So you want to call `.Next()` from any element, no matter where it came from? (eg: `dataStructure[20].Next()`)

Comment: @willem I got it now. If you implement by yourself a AVL or Red-Black Tree you can do that (almost by default) in `O(logn)`

Comment: O(N log (N)) does not seem very fast?

Comment: And of course, if you do some tweaks to the data structure, you can have it in `O(1)` too. All you have to do is kind of a linked-list (same same tree, but also adding to every node a reference to the next one), and handling that correctly when inserting/eliminating. I implemented an AVL in C# for a university project about a year ago and I did it in `O(logn)`. `O(1)` wasn't a requirement

Comment: Will maintaining this linked list not complicate rebalancing? Was implementing AVL a lot of work? Any good references?

Comment: @willem sorry. I meant `O(logn)` :).

Comment: About complicating rebalancing... I would have to think about AVL rotations, but now I would say that no, it isn't a problem.

Comment: @willem I did it in no more than two days, although I remember I had to fix a bug days ago because it wasn't 100% balanced. A good reference is *Introductions to Algorithms* book. It explains every rotation pretty well. I suggest you implementing it. Then you can make it generic and have a copy of it for every project with similar requirements :)

Comment: I would first go with a regular AVL tree - without the linked-listed-leafs. If you need such, consider a B tree instead. But, no, log N is not much in general.

Answer (score 0):

I once had similar requirements and was unable to find something suitable. So I implemented an AVL tree. Here come some advices to do it with performance in mind:

1. Do not use recursion for walking the tree (insert, update, delete, next). Better use a stack array to store the way up to the root which is needed for balancing operations.
2. Do not store parent nodes. All operations will start from the root node and walk further down. Parents are not needed, if implemented carefully.
3. In order to find the Next() node of an existing one, usually Find() is first called. The stack produced by that, should be reused for Next() than.

By following these rules, I was able to implement the AVL tree. It is working very efficiently even for very large data sets. I would be willing to share, but it would need some modifications, since it does not store values (very easy) and does not rely on IComparable but on fixed key types of int.

Comment: If you would be willing to share: great! Modifications appear to be easy. In any case, thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The OrderedDictionary in PowerCollections provides a "get iterator starting at or before key" function that takes O(log N) time to return the first value.  That makes it very fast to, say, scan the 1,000 items that are near the middle of a 50 million item set (which with SortedDictionary would require guessing to start at the start or the end, both of which are equally bad choices and would require iterator around 25 million items).  OrderedDictionary can to that with just 1,000 items iterated.

There is a problem in OrderedDictionary though in that it uses yield which causes O(n^2) performance and out of memory conditions when iterating a 50 million item set in a 32 bit process.  There is a quite simple fix for that while I will document later.